# Chef recipe not executing on first convergence

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I've basic chef cookbook and one of the recipes does not converge in the first run.

Chef Cookbook: https://github.com/linaksa/linaksa_infra

When I run `kitchen test` the recipe `linaksa_infra::hosts` does not get converge at all. Also when I run `kitchen setup` it does not get converge but if I run `kitchen converge` after then it does. I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Here is the output of `kitchen test` `kitchen setup` and `kitchen converge`: https://gist.github.com/linaksa/76607bbfd15e471dfa67

I am using Chef DK 0.10.0. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, the recipe is executed in both cases.

The problem is that the recipe is printed on the screen only **if at least contains a resource inside it**.

Looking at the recipe code:

```ruby
nodes = search(:node, 'ipaddress:*')
nodes.each do |n|
  hostsfile_entry n['ipaddress'] do
    # [...]
  end
end
```

The reason is that the first time the search returns no nodes (we are using kitchen). So in the first run this recipe will not create any resource. Therefore, the recipe will not be displayed on screen as executed.

The second time, if you are using `chef_zero` provisioner the search will return the localhost machine because it was saved at the end of the previous chef run.

You can try running kitchen with `-l debug` to confirm what is going on.